# Divs With Same Class - Only Allow One To Be Open At Any One Time Issue

Tags: jquery

I've set up a page with some team profiles.

In the CSS, all profile descriptions are hidden to begin with.

When a profile is clicked, I reveal the description for that profile.

At the same time I want the previous one that was opened to close.

This code all works fine, however if I try to close the one that is currently opened, then it closes and then opens again.

When I read through the code, I can see why this is happening, but I'm not sure how I just close an open profile without having it open again?

**HTML**

```
<div class="profile">

    <img src="img/profile.jpg" />

    <p>Name</p>

    <p>Job Title</p>

    <p class="text"></p>

    <div class="description">

        <p>Blah blah blah</p>

    </div> <!-- description -->

</div> <!-- .profile -->
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.team p.text').prepend('Biog');

    $('.team .profile', this).click(function(e) {

        $('.description').slideUp();    

        $('p.text').text('Biog');

        var change = $(this).find('p.text');

        $('.description', this).slideToggle(1000, 'linear', function() {

            change.text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close biog' : 'Biog');

        });

        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

All help and time is greatly appreciated.

Comment: An example of *your* HTML would help demonstrate any fix.

Comment: An example of your HTML, including the `.team` elements, would be even better. :)

Comment: .team is just the class applied to the body :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal solution is to exclude the "current" panel from the slideup, e.g. using not:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.team p.text').prepend('Biog');
    $('.team .profile', this).click(function(e) {
        $('p.text').text('Biog');
        var change = $(this).find('p.text');
        $('.description').not($('.description', this).slideToggle(1000, 'linear', function() {
            change.text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close biog' : 'Biog');
        })).slideUp();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

*Apologies for not making the code clearer, but without HTML... (hint)*

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I have added my HTML to the original question as it may help someone else in the future.